# Local Xeams standalone server not sending emails?

Tags: ubuntu, email-server, smtp

I want to setup a Ruby On Rails development environment where I can develop an application that can send emails. I can use the `smtp.gmail.com` free server but I do not want to use it, but rather I want to use a local smtp server. I Installed Xeams server as a standalone mail server. The server is running normally but I cannot send emails. 
for example:
the hostname is `localmail.com` 
here what I get when I try to send email from the command-line

```
nafaa@localmail:~$ telnet localmail.com 25
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localmail.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 Xeams SMTP server;  Version: 4.4 - build: 5735; 1/4/15 6:29 PM
ehlo localmail.com
250-localhost. Please to meet you
250-SIZE 20971520
250-AUTH LOGIN
250-AUTH=LOGIN
250 OK
MAIL FROM: myaccount@localmail.com
250 OK
RCPT TO: myaccount@gmail.com
250 OK
DATA
354 Start mail input; end with <CRLF>.<CRLF>
subject: hello from cmd line

body: hello I am an email from the command line through Xeams
.
250 2.6.0 Queued mail for delivery
```

Why the email is just Queued for delivery?
When I enter through the Xeams Admin Console, I find the email but I do not find it on the remote inbox. 
What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Start by checking the [Xeams log file](http://www.xeams.com/logging.htm) because that sounds like a default message for a SMTP server, it confirms a message has been received and "*queued*" and will start transmitting it to the intended recipient.

Comment: What have you done to troubleshoot this? Have you read the documentation? Have you checked the log files?

Comment: @HBruijn it stay like that until I quit. It should say `250 OK` when the email is successfully transmitted.

Comment: @joeqwerty yes I checked there documentation, I find it so poor, especially for a beginner like me.